# MyBatis - Join on the same table returns wrong values

Tags: java, mybatis

I try to get 2 different records from the same table joined with different key in one join, but I get the same object twice. The query is:

```
SELECT  ISID, ISISIN, ISNMRC, ISTIME, ISTEXT, ISPZDT, ISZADA, ISPOPL,
     petitioner.POICO, petitioner.PONMAF,  petitioner.POADSI,  petitioner.POIDMA,
     ADSTR, ADPSC,ADCIT,
     bic.BCLCVA, bic.BCBIC, bic.BCPOCP, bic.BCICO,
     emitent.PONMAF, emitent.POICO
    FROM FVIS00 as isin
    left outer join FEPO00 as petitioner on isin.ISZADA = petitioner.POID
    left outer join FEAD00 as address on petitioner.POADSI = address.ADID
    left outer join FVBC00 as bic on isin.ISISIN = bic.BCCDVA
    left outer join FEPO00 as emitent on bic.BCICO = emitent.POICO
```

result map:

```
<resultMap type="ISIN" id="isin">
    <result property="id" column="ISID"/>
    <result property="isin" column="ISISIN"/>
    <result property="user" column="ISNMRC"/>
    <result property="created" column="ISTIME"/>
    <result property="submited" column="ISPZDT"/>
    <result property="text" column="ISTEXT"/>
    <result property="fee" column="ISPOPL"/>
    <association property="petitioner" javaType="LegalPerson" column="ISZADA">
        <result property="ico" column="POICO"/>
        <result property="name" column="PONMAF"/>
         <association property="address" javaType="Address" column="POADSI">
            <result property="street" column="ADSTR"/>
            <result property="code" column="ADPSC"/>
            <result property="town" column="ADCIT"/>
         </association>
    </association>
    <association property="bic" javaType="BIC" column="BCCDVA">
        <result property="shortName" column="BCLCVA"/>
        <result property="bic" column="BCBIC"/>
        <result property="form" column="BCPOCP"/>
        <result property="ico" column="BCICO"/>
        <association property="emitent" javaType="LegalPerson" column="BCICO" >
            <result property="name" column="PONMAF"/>
            <result property="ico" column="POICO"/>
        </association>
    </association>
</resultMap>
```

but I always get *emitent* with the values of *petitioner*:

```
##                                                                   |                   petitoner                 |                                                                                              |               emitent                     |                    ##
CS0005001502    22. 08. 2005    07. 05. 2010 11.22:06.000    580,00    47115629    Burza cenných papírů Praha a.s.    11005    Praha 1            Rybná 14                         BAACISBO    list    00486949    47115629    Burza cenných papírů Praha a.s.    PR_LR    převod z SCP
CS0005001544    23. 08. 2005    07. 05. 2010 11.22:06.000    580,00    47115629    Burza cenných papírů Praha a.s.    11005    Praha 1            Rybná 14                         BABCISBO    list    00486949    47115629    Burza cenných papírů Praha a.s.    PR_LR    převod z SCP
CS0005002864    24. 08. 2005    07. 05. 2010 11.22:06.000    580,00    00002127    AERO,                              19904    Praha 9-letňany    Beranových 130    AERO           BAAAERO     zakn    00002127    00002127    AERO, a.s.                         PR_LR    převod z SCP
CS0005002963    25. 08. 2005    07. 05. 2010 11.22:06.000    580,00    47115629    Burza cenných papírů Praha a.s.    11005    Praha 1            Rybná 14          ČKD BLANSKO    BAACKDBK    zakn    00002208    47115629    Burza cenných papírů Praha a.s.    PR_LR    převod z SCP
```

Expected result:

```
##                                                             |                   petitoner                 |                                                                                          |            emitent                   |                    ##
CS0005001502  2010-05-07-11.22.06.000000 2005-08-22     580,00   47115629  Burza cenných papírù Praha a.s.         11005   Praha 1               Rybná 14                               BAACISBO   list   00486949  null     null                PR_LR převod z SCP
CS0005001544  2010-05-07-11.22.06.000000 2005-08-23     580,00   47115629  Burza cenných papírù Praha a.s.         11005   Praha 1               Rybná 14                               BABCISBO   list   00486949  null     null                PR_LR převod z SCP
CS0005002864  2010-05-07-11.22.06.000000 2005-08-24     580,00   00002127  AERO, a.s.                              19904   Praha 9-letòany       Beranových 130          AERO           BAAAERO    zakn   00002127  00002127 AERO, a.s.          PR_LR převod z SCP
CS0005002963  2010-05-07-11.22.06.000000 2005-08-25     580,00   47115629  Burza cenných papírù Praha a.s.         11005   Praha 1               Rybná 14                ČKD BLANSKO    BAACKDBK   zakn   00002208  00002208 ÈKD Blansko, a.s.   PR_LR převod z SCP
```

As you can see, emitent has always the same values as petitioner and the join key has different values for both tables (field left to emitent)

Do I make something wrong or is it bug in MyBatis?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Agata

Comment: Have you run the query directly against the database (without MyBatis) using its command-line interface?

Comment: `Expected result` is output from the query, when running on terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that its a naming-clash issue - MyBatis can't distinguish the different columns. Can you rename the clashing columns?

```
SELECT  ISID, ISISIN, ISNMRC, ISTIME, ISTEXT, ISPZDT, ISZADA, ISPOPL,
     petitioner.POICO, petitioner.PONMAF,  petitioner.POADSI,  petitioner.POIDMA,
     ADSTR, ADPSC,ADCIT,
     bic.BCLCVA, bic.BCBIC, bic.BCPOCP, bic.BCICO,
     emitent.PONMAF AS emitentPONMAF, emitent.POICO AS emitentPOICO
    FROM FVIS00 as isin
    left outer join FEPO00 as petitioner on isin.ISZADA = petitioner.POID
    left outer join FEAD00 as address on petitioner.POADSI = address.ADID
    left outer join FVBC00 as bic on isin.ISISIN = bic.BCCDVA
    left outer join FEPO00 as emitent on bic.BCICO = emitent.POICO
```

Hideous names for the columns and tables by the way! `FEPO00` really?! :-)

Comment: Thank you !!!! :-) The names are terrible. This is 20 year old system :-( and some people still think it is the best system :-&

Comment: You have my heartfelt sympathy!